# How to convert a 5 digit number to a date in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a 5 digit number 37988 and I want it to be converted to a date using Javascript

I tried to search relevant methods. But couldn't find one

Comment: Suppose the number is `37988`,then what's the expected result?

Comment: @flyingfox expected result is -2nd January 2004

Comment: @KrishnaTeja why? What's the conversion logic for this?

Comment: This is a tricky requirement, due to leap years (and even leap _seconds_).

Comment: So the number is a day or so off number of days since 1900-01-01 - so SQL/Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

credits: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/369

```js
const convertDateExcel = (excelTimestamp) => {
  // 1. Subtract number of days between Jan 1, 1900 and Jan 1, 1970, plus 1 (Google "excel leap year bug")
  // 2. Convert to milliseconds.
  const secondsInDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
  const excelEpoch = new Date(1899, 11, 31);
  const excelEpochAsUnixTimestamp = excelEpoch.getTime();
  const missingLeapYearDay = secondsInDay * 1000;
  const delta = excelEpochAsUnixTimestamp - missingLeapYearDay;
  const excelTimestampAsUnixTimestamp = excelTimestamp * secondsInDay * 1000;
  const parsed = excelTimestampAsUnixTimestamp + delta;
  return isNaN(parsed) ? null : new Date(parsed);
};
console.log(
  convertDateExcel(37988)
);  
// Date Thu Jan 01 2004
```

Comment: I just added it

Comment: When run in a timezone UTC+10 this returns "2004-01-01T14:21:00.000Z" which, locally, is "2004-01-02T00:21:00". So something is awry somewhere. ;-) It may be a hint that it treats the values as local but does calculations as UTC.